# Why doesn't zsh syntax work in this script?

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm just trying to understand what is happening here, so that I understand how to parse strings in shell scripts better.

I know that usually, when you try to pass a string of arguments separated by spaces directly to a command, they will be treated as a single string argument and therefore not recognized:

```
>check="FileA.txt FileB.txt"
>ls $check
ls: cannot access FileA.txt FileB.txt: No such file or directory
```

However, in this script  two arguments are taken each as space separated strings. In this case, both strings are recognizes as lists of arguments that can be passed to different commands:

**testscript.sh**

```
while getopts o:p: arguments
do  
    case $arguments in
    o) olist="$OPTARG";;
    p) plist=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done
echo "olist"
ls -l $olist
echo "plist"
ls -l $plist
```

the output is then as follows:

```
>testscript.sh -o "fileA.txt fileB.txt" -p "file1.txt file2.txt"
Olist
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
plist
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

What is different here? Why are the space separated strings suddenly recognized as lists?

Comment: Are you executing `ls $check` and `testscript.sh` in the same directory?

Comment: @klaus The Title was accedently abbreviated before submitting. I edited it immediately.

Comment: @condorwasabi: Yes they are both executed in the same directory

Answer (score 2):

Your script does not start with a `#!`-line and does therefore not specify an interpreter. In that case the default is used, which is `/bin/sh` and not your login shell or the shell you are starting the script from (unless that is `/bin/sh` of course). Chances are good that `/bin/sh` is not a `zsh`, as most distributions and Unices seem to use `sh`, `bash`, `dash` or `ksh` as default shell. All of which handle parameter expansion such that strings are handles as lists if the parameter was not quoted with double-quotes.

If you want to use `zsh` as interpreter for your scripts, you have to specify it in the first line of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
```

Modify the path to wherever your `zsh` resides.

You can also use `env` as a wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
```

This makes you more independent of the actual location of `zsh`, it just has to be in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact (using bash)...

```
sh$ check="FileA.txt FileB.txt"
sh$ ls $check
ls: cannot access FileA.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access FileB.txt: No such file or directory
```

When you write `$check` without quotes, the variable is *substituted* by its content. Insides paces (or to be precises inside occurrences of IFS) are considered as field separators. Just as you where expecting it first.

The only way I know to reproduce your behavior is to set IFS to something else than its default value:

```
sh$ export IFS="-"
sh$ check="FileA.txt FileB.txt"
sh$ ls $check
ls: cannot access FileA.txt FileB.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I just realized i working with zsh not bash. So that seems to be the problem right there (zsh treats space separated strings differently than bash). But I still don't understand why the behaviour is so different when using the shell script